# Lazy load error in Propel

Tags: lazy-loading, propel

I am adding `lazyLoad` attribute for each `column` in my propel `schema.xml`. The option for this attribute are true or false `([lazyLoad = "true|{false}"]`).

Here is my `schema.xml`

[Schema.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFzAj.jpg)

whenever I set the option to true, I got the following message error each time I run the query that has inner join to another table.

[propel.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0zm9.jpg)

Kindly any help to figure out the answer how to fix this `lazyLoad` problem.

Comment: The `lazyLoad` attribute is true by default, why do you need to set it to true again?

Also, your Schema.xml link is just showing a query log